# An error occurred loading a configuration file:The system cannot open the file (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, parallels

So I have installed visual studio on Mac (Using Parallels) it works great when creating new MVC project. But Now when I open my solution which consists of 35 projects), when I hit build, it throws the following error on the startup project:

> An error occurred loading a configuration file:The system cannot open the file.

Now I have searched this up but none of the errors are this vague, this doesn't even mention what the exact issue is, just says system cannot open the file. And BTW the file it cannot open is `WEB.CONFIG` (Located in Views directory) in the main project.
I would really appreciate it if anyone knows about this error and how to fix it.
Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried running Parallels Desktop and running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Parallels 11. I had to downgrade to Parallels 10.
We are not alone with this : http://forum.parallels.com/threads/parallels-11-shared-home-folder-disappears-win8-1-visual-studio-2013-iis-express.329413/
Regards,